# Three JS - 3D mesh not displaying

Tags: three.js

So I've been trying to get my mesh into my scene but cannot get it working at all. I've been looking for tutorials on how to do it, trying all kinds of things for the last hour and a half but cannot get it to show up at all.

Here's my code so far:

```
$(function() {
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

  var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(); 
      loader.load( "stand2.js", modelLoadedCallback);


  var meshmaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      wireframe: true,
      color: 0xdddddd
        });

  function modelLoadedCallback(geometry) {
     var standmesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, meshmaterial);
      standmesh.position.x = 0;
      standmesh.position.y = 0;
      standmesh.position.z = 0;
      standmesh.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
      scene.add(standmesh);
  }



  renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  var axis = new THREE.AxisHelper(10);
  scene.add(axis);

  var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 20, 20);
  var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xdddddd,
    wireframe: true
  });
  var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);

  cube.position.x = 0;
  cube.position.y = 0;
  cube.position.z = 0;

  scene.add(cube);

  camera.position.x = 300;
  camera.position.y = 300;
  camera.position.z = 300;

  camera.lookAt(scene.position);

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.02;
    cube.rotation.z +=0.01
}
render();   
  $("#webGL-container").append(renderer.domElement);

});
```

I've got a simple rotating cube that shows up perfectly fine, but cannot get my mesh to show up. I've tried messing with it's scale incase it was too big or too small but nothing has worked. Exported it twice using the 3DSMax exporter but it changes nothing. There's no light source, but I'm just focused on seeing a wireframe of it for the time being.
The exported model is also in the same directory of this js file, so the directory isn't wrong either.

Sorry for asking such a basic question but I've honestly been at this for a solid 1h30m+ and cannot get anything to show up.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: your code is working ~fine to me, are you sure the html is correct ? ("#webGL-container" does exist and no typos, etc..)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something? I have no clue, but from what I've seen my html should be OK too.
[This is what I have for it.](http://i.imgur.com/1kdIvZD.png)

Comment: can you share your HTML maybe ?